# serialize objective-c custom object to JSON for OSX?

Tags: objective-c, json, macos, serialization

I'm very new to Mac development and I'm having some troubles finding good resources. My current problem is a custom objective-c class object serialization to JSON.

I know that there is a built-in serializer in apple libraries, but that one works only with Foundation objects.

In my case I have my own class that looks like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
   int a;
   int b;
   NSString *aa;
   NSString *bb;
}
@property int a,b;
@property NSString *aa,*bb;

@end
```

If anyone knows how to serialize this type of structure to a JSON please give me a hint! Any kind of relevant information would help! Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to serialize the images?  Do you want to embed the image data in the JSON, perhaps in PNG or JPEG format?

Comment: oh...sorry...I'll change it to just the simple NSString *imageName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to serialize an object that contains integers and strings, the easiest way is to create a data structure that `NSJSONSerialization` supports and serialize that:

```
static const NSString *kAKey = @"a";
static const NSString *kBKey = @"b";
static const NSString *kAaKey = @"aa";
static const NSString *kBbKey = @"bb";

- (id)JSONObject {
    return @{
        kAKey: @(self.a),
        kBKey: @(self.b),
        kAaKey: self.aa,
        kBbKey: self.bb
    };
}

- (NSData *)JSONData {
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self JSONObject] options:0 error:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this for the past week. I decided to write my own solution. It is very simple and built upon existing Apple functionality.

See here: https://github.com/gslinker/GSObject

And here: http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2016/01/objective-c-and-json-convert-subclass.html

For your data model object have it inherit from GSObject instead of NSObject. Here is an example of ThingOne with inherits from GSObject:

```
ThingOne* object1 = [[ThingOne alloc] init];
object1.name = @"John Jones";


NSData* jsonData1 = [object1 toJsonDataWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
NSString *jsonString1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];

NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *dict1 =  [GSObject dictionaryWithValues:object1];

NSString *roundTripJson1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];




//
//  ThingOne.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"
#import "ThingTwo.h"

@interface ThingOne : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ThingTwo *thingTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *values;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dict;
@property int myInt;
@property float myFloat;
@property BOOL myBool;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* someMoney;


@end

//
//  ThingOne.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingOne.h"

@implementation ThingOne

@synthesize name;
@synthesize thingTwo;
@synthesize values;
@synthesize dict;
@synthesize myInt;
@synthesize myFloat;
@synthesize myBool;
@synthesize someMoney;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

thingTwo = [[ThingTwo alloc] init];

thingTwo.stuff = @"Thing Two Stuff";
thingTwo.someOtherStuff = @"Thing Two Other Stuff";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
thingTwo.someDate =  [dateFormater dateFromString:@"1963-10-07"];

values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value1", @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

myInt = 5431;
myFloat = 123.456f;
myBool = YES;

someMoney = [NSNumber numberWithInt:503];

return self;
}

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"

@interface ThingTwo : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someOtherStuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *someDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nullString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *nullDate;

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingTwo.h"

@implementation ThingTwo

@synthesize stuff;
@synthesize someOtherStuff;
@synthesize someDate;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

someDate = [NSDate date];

return self;
}

@end
```

Here is an example of the JSON output:

```
{
  "values" : [
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"
  ],
  "myInt" : 5431,
  "myFloat" : 123.456,
  "myBool" : true,
  "someMoney" : "$503.00",
  "thingTwo" : {
    "stuff" : "Thing Two Stuff",
    "nullDate" : null,
    "someDate" : "1963-01-07 07:10:00 +0000",
    "nullString" : null,
    "someOtherStuff" : "Thing Two Other Stuff"
  },
  "name" : "John Jones",
  "dict" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
  }
}
```